# Searching for an Op Amp which amplifies an input voltage of 3mv to say +-5v

Tags: operational-amplifier

It would be really helpful if someone suggests an Op Amp which takes an input voltage in mV and the output of +-5v. If there's an evaluation board that comes with the Op amp which takes the mv input and gives a +- 5V output, then it would be even more helpful.

Comment: Virtually an op-amp will do this. Product suggestions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Pretty much any op-amp will do that. Some will do it better than others, but without specifications it's  hard to tell whether that's important. You'll need a couple power supplies and some resistors and a capacitor or two. Picking the components to match the requirements is where the engineering part comes in.

Comment: That's a gain of around 1000 for a small (< +/- 5mV) input. I would use an instrumentation amplifier for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a supply of more than ±5V, you should be able to pick pretty much any op-amp and it will be able to do what you are wanting. It is all dependant on the feedback resistors used.

It will likely be much cheaper to stick a circuit on breadboard or a bit of stripboard and use a DIP socket to change the op-amp than it would be to buy a EV board. You could have female sockets for resistor pins to plug into as well so you can change the resistor values in the feedback loop.

EV boards can be upwards of $20 (some better op amps will be much more) whereas you can probably build your own with interchangeable parts for less than $5, and you'll be able to see virtually any op-amp can give you your desired output with a mV input.